# Why aren’t the Elementals hurt by material weapons?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

Spider-Man is throwing large objects (blocks of concrete, ...) at the Elemental.

**Since the Elemental is a set of drones flying together why aren't they just destroyed when hit by it?**

This would at least create a hole in the illusion, if not impede the ability of the Elemental to destroy things around him - uncovering the set-up.

Are the objects thrown at them shot by the drones before they get a chance to touch him? (I do not remember if at any point Spider-Man’s throws were actually successful to hit the Elemental).

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, let’s consider how Peter and MJ realised the Elementals were fake. They’d found a projector that had been broken off of Molten-Man and had seen what it was doing. So at least some of the attacks damaged the drones. But why didn’t the others? Well we have a few possibilities.

1. They did but the illusion tech just covered up for the fact with extra drones.
2. The drones shot down whatever was coming at them and so it didn’t damage them.
3. In London when Peter gets inside the illusion of Elemental Fusion we see that there is a lot of drones and a lot going on. However, we also see that there is a lot of empty space and so it is possible that a lot of the earlier attacks just missed.
4. The drones can dodge the attacks that come at them, they do seem to be quite fast considering how quick one got from the satellite to the bus when Peter accidentally calls in the kill strike.

It is quite probable that the reason the attacks didn’t do too much damage is a combination of all three factors together with the drones most certainly defending themselves against in coming attacks.

Comment: Also if I remember correctly the molten man drone was projecting from outside molten man, so hitting it was a huge fluke.

Comment: @Jack Been too long since I've seen it but can't remember that part. It is possible though as they could cloak themselves.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yeah they could cloak themself. And it was a (rather short) scene where Spiderman shoot a web and hit the drone and we saw the drone crashin to an ally where MJ hid. I was quite suprised that this was never mentioned in the movie as it seemed iirc that there was a bit of suprise in Spidermans face/reaction

Comment: The projector was damaged when Spider-Man was trying to attach a web to the ferris wheel, either to help anchor it or to let him move to it. He was surprised because he was expecting a solid and heavy surface but ended up with a tiny piece of tech. The projector flew a long ways because it's a small mass pulled with the force that Spidey would use to move himself.